# Find all triplets $(a,b,c)$ where $ab=c^2$

Tags: number-theory

Given a set of numbers $\{ 1,2,\dots , n\}$, how can we find all the triplets $(a,b,c)$ which satisfy the expression $ab = c^2$  ?

What I have tried:

**1.** One method is to try each combination, but it's to slow.

**2.** Another method is to find $ab$ which are perfect squares, but again it's slow.

**3.** The last method that I can think of, is to break $c^2$ into prime factors and get $a$, $b$ (not sure if this is correct).

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** find first the solutions for which $gcd(a,b)=1$.

For those solutions, both $a,b$ are perfect squares.

In this case, the problem boils to find all $1 \leq k,m \leq n$ such that $$km \leq n$.

**Step 2:** you can find all the solutions: If $a,b,c$ is a solution and $d=gcd(a,b)$ then $a'=\frac{a}{d}, b'=\frac{b}{d}, c'=\frac{c}{d}$ is a solution with $gcd(a',b')=1$.

Therefore, each solution with $gcd(a,b)=1$ produces the solutions
$$ja,jb,jc$$
with 
$$1 \leq j \leq \frac{n}{e}$$
where 
$$e=\max \{ a,b,c \}$$